# How can we find a function for $\mathbb{Q}^{<0}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $\wp\left( \mathbb{Q} \right) ^{\ast }=\wp\left( \mathbb{Q}\right) \backslash \{ \emptyset\}$. Find  $f: \wp\left( \mathbb{Q}\right) ^{\ast}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ such that for all $x \in\left( \mathbb{Q} \right) ^{\ast }$ implies that $f\left( x\right) \in x$.

First case. We show firstly for $\mathbb{Q}^{>0}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}^{>0}$ is a countable set, we can match from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. For instance,  $0\rightarrow \dfrac {1} {1}$, $1\rightarrow \dfrac {1} {2}$, $2\rightarrow \dfrac {2} {1}$,  $3\rightarrow \dfrac {2} {2}$ ..., that is, $f(X)=min(X)$ is defined as a function.

XXXQuestion:How can we find a function for $\mathbb{Q}^{<0}$?

Comment: What do the $\phi$s here mean? Should they have been $\mathcal P$ (or even $\mathscr P$ or $\wp$, all with the same meaning)?

Comment: it means ℘ @Makholm

Comment: How sad that no-one has mentioned $\Bbb{P}$, the powerset I grew up on.

Comment: @RobArthan $\phi$ means powerset here.

Comment: Well, please edit your question to use one of the standard notations. $\phi$ is not a standard notation for the powerset operation. Also did you mean "choice function" rather than "function" in your title?

Comment: @RobArthan thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: your method for $\Bbb{Q}^{>0}$ works for any countable set. $\Bbb{Q}$ is countable too, so you are done.

Comment: Hah! Yes, of course. Thanks.